# Get value from new input element on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a problem in getting the value from a dynamic added input field.
I have a function that does a ajax call and in the end I add a input field like this:

```
$('<input type="text" id="col_1" value="done" hidden="true"/>').appendTo("#progress-category");
```

This part works just well, but my problem comes when on another function I need to get the value from my input on page load.

So when my page load I need to get the value check if it's equal to "done" and do some other stuff.

The usual way :
`$("#col_1").val()` on `alert()` prints undefined.

I read about the `.on` function for dinamically added elements, but I don't want to bind the getting value phase on an certain even, I need that value as soon as my page is loaded.

Comment: when this input is added to page?

Comment: On page load the element col_1 is not present in DOM, You must get it after being added through ajax call

Comment: how you will get value of `#col1`, where it's not available in DOM, you said that it's appending on ajax call.

Comment: Just to make i clear: When my page loads first it does the ajax that adds my input. When this function is done, I'm trying to get the value from the input i just added.

Comment: Put the call to your "other function" in the success callback of your ajax request. ajax is asynchronous so your code is trying to retrieve the value of the input before the request is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to trigger event when you have added this input

Eg:

```
$('<input type="text" id="col_1" value="done" hidden="true"/>').appendTo("#progress-category");
$(window).trigger("inputIsadded");
```

After this you can add listener to "inputIsadded" event.

Eg.

```
$(window).on("inputIsadded", function() {
    // working with input 
});
```

Other approach is to use [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.